# "Anonymous user" trying to destroy posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

There has been a user active for the past 3 days destroying posts.  I'm seeing the edit approval prompts and have consistently rejected them.  The typical edit is deleting content and replacing it with a dumb remark.  Or adding random characters.

I cannot find out who it is, the page doesn't provide a way to get to this profile.  Only "anonymous user" is visible.  It could well be more than one.  There are two basic patterns, erase content and adding random keystrokes.  The total number of edits I've personally rejected is around 20 or so.

No real harm done but this is getting old.  I have to say that I see no reason at all why users that don't log in should have edit permissions.  Any of the users that make legit edits have been named users.  Please consider making these kind of users at least traceable.

Comment: I agree. While it's community-run, I don't see a need for someone to be able to edit anonymously.

Comment: Do you have permalinks to the destructive suggested edits? The SO team probably has IP info and can ban.

Comment: @wai - I don't, these edits disappear quickly.

Comment: @Hans On the suggested edits, on the left, there is a permalink which will be preserved even if the edit is rejected. If you see this happening again and could grab the permalink, I think that would help the Team.

Comment: @Hans .. if the edit is rejected it disappears from the page. If we dont remember the question how can we get the perm link?

Comment: Here is one good example: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/64485 - judge for yourselves. (Yes the "anonymous user" is back at full strength probably took him this long to bypass the obstacles set by Jeff)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some additional restrictions on anonymous user edits that should prevent these sorts of anonymous edits from entering the queue at all. These restrictions are based on the history of the known anonymous bad faith edits.

I can't describe them in detail because that would be a recipe for bypassing them.

Comment: Security through obscurity?

Comment: It failed. the anonymous user is back and destroying posts again for at least 5 hours straight now. Already used all my votes, rejected most of the suggestions, though few were good enough to approve. Naturally, he's also clogging the queue, preventing registered members from suggesting edits.

Comment: @shadow there was a bug which made all edits show up as anonymous for a bit; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96000/suggested-edits-review-page-shows-the-user-who-proposed-the-edit-as-anonymous-use

Comment: Thanks, it just looked like the same person making most of those suggestions, many times adding meaningless contents to existing posts or just doing useless changes in old answers.

Comment: I agree with the sentance. Message me if you're curious.

Comment: @MichaelMackus what sentence you agree with? There is no private messages in Stack Exchange and nothing in your profile page so how you want anyone to "message you" exactly?

Answer (score 10):

Some stats about **anonymous**:

From inception we had 91 rejected edits and 82 approved edits. The vast majority of edits come in from registered users (I am counting about 4200 now from registered users)

Of these anonymous users the top number of submissions we got from a single ip address is 4.

The **3 anonymous** users that have more than 2 submissions all submitted good content.

---

So it appears that DISASTA PASTA, is coming our way not from a single anonymous source but many distinct IP Addresses .

Even at this low hit rate, many of these edits anonymous is posting are good.

At the moment if a single anonymous account is rejected N times per day the IP is auto banned for a week. So we already have some protection.

---

To add to that we could add a second param that auto reject edits where anon is [clearly vandalizing a post](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/4357). Perhaps if more than 80% of the post is changed by anonymous it is silently auto-rejected.

---

Here is a full list of all the rejected anonymous edits from the start, let me know if you can think of simple heuristic to cut this down:

- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/6)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/14)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/16)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/18)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/20)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/24)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/35)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/37)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/38)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/46)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/54)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/58)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/59)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/61)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/65)
- [improved formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/171)
- [correct spelling](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/174)
- [No signing. Formatting.](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/179)
- [added a versioning comment](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/196)
- [config did not have a capital C](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/204)
- [revert changes](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/294)
- [rephrasing the question](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/310)
- [Edited , this idiot is a time waster ... doent enen know what the question was...](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/314)
- [2 parts of answer incorrect and misleading](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/346)
- [can you give some example sir ???? that will be helpful for us..](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/369)
- [Noted important points about the references in the post and added what was really expected](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/450)
- [optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/611)
- [i want to write the retrieved string to a file in the format i'v shown !!!](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/688)
- [Dressed the naked link (indirectly). Reformatted the sample XML (indent).](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/737)
- [there was an error when finding phi, the sqrt(xy) should be divded by z. It was in the wrong order](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/756)
- [Copy editing.](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/834)
- [Copy editing.](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/835)
- [My blog address changed](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/990)
- [ghjghjghjgjhgjhghjghjghj](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1022)
- [jkhjkhkjhkjhjk](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1024)
- [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1236)
- [Confirmation that technique mentioned works.](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1261)
- [Better to use serviceInstaller.ServiceName, if the servicename gets changed it will use the correct name without needing to change it in the code.](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1264)
- [moved to superuser per suggestion - I'm original author](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1561)
- [Update on the solution chosen.](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1804)
- [do detail study of mapping in my sql.](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1840)
- [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2033)
- [I belive that we are looking at it all wrong...we need to find ways of slowing it down not stopping it...we use probability to re-invent coded locks from the uncoded ones...](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2087)
- [Improved the answer by adding a custom class that solves the problem very simply](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2101)
- [explain...](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2120)
- [please reconsider this question](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2314)
- [update to status](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2405)
- [Others may have the same issue I had - example mentioned doesn't work properly in Firefox v3.6.13 on one of my computers but not another, may be a plugin issue (I'm *not* using NoScript on the computer that has the problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2479)
- [2354545645656](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2801)
- [replace bob  screen name with our name](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2875)
- [Removed override of onConfigurationChanged.](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2883)
- [Look into this](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2937)
- [ererreeeeeeeeeeeeeeee](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2996)
- [fdsfdsaffffffffff sdaf sda fsdaf sad fdsfewg t fgfh fg](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3029)
- [New version](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3060)
- [corrected the inherit element](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3105)
- [Additional Question](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3207)
- [Commented on the answer with a simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3290)
- [xxxxxxxxxxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3344)
- [write free bug code](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3346)
- [more of a question. can be removed from this site](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3373)
- [sadfsadfasdf asdf asdf asdf](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3386)
- [Good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3462)
- [Refactoring is supported. Comments to the contrary are obsolete.](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3476)
- [i went to the website, and there was a message about google having acquired them](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3499)
- [00gryrtyryr](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3516)
- [x](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3614)
- [It has been solved](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3674)
- [changed your "xhtml1-strict.dtd" to "xhtml1-transitional.dtd" to match with its proper doc type](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3683)
- [vgbh gbh h h](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3709)
- [1556666666666666666666](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3712)
- [No need to add the variable to registry explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3773)
- [Found a link for the post](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3845)
- [Delegate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3886)
- [memmove(s, start, end-start+**2**); --> Must be 2 to copy the NULL char too.](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3927)
- [45y645yttyhutyu](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3930)
- [testing the function](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3994)
- [jkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkl](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3995)
- [fixed the error](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/4052)
- [bgfhrhjfdhgdm](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/4101)
- [vghnjtrrzutrzu](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/4102)
- [sdasdcvsdafdsfdasf](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/4109)
- [Problem solved](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/4119)
- [1111111111111111111111](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/4212)
- [frserwergftewrt werw](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/4259)
- [I'm a prick](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/4268)
- [Address the latest version of ANY software product with a solution. An automatic question repost?](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/4276)
- [ciao website](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/4336)
- [very nice answer. i love ur solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/4357)

Comment: I like the silent auto-reject. Perhaps apply the same heuristics as we use with detecting crappy answers?

Comment: low entropy comment seems like a good one as well ...

Comment: How about introducing a "reject as spam/trash" vote that needs to be confirmed by one other user, with much higher limtis? Not sure whether this can ever be reliably filtered out automatically...

Comment: I also find it *fascinating* that people actually mistake the edit function for the comment field (or simply don't give a damn). See "Very nice answer. i love ur solution" and "can you give some example sir ???? that will be helpful for us.."

Comment: @Pekka: my thoughts exactly! *Grabs his jaw from ground*

Comment: I'm pretty active on reviewing edits, and I've not yet seen one of these, so well done everyone that's rapidly rejecting them

Comment: I wonder if there's more of this: http://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/834 (reject somebody's edit) → http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2108300/revisions (then make it yourself). It could be that the user clicked reject accidentally then applied the edit anyway, or it could be an attempt to game the system.

Comment: @badp ... most likely an accident ... it is too much effort to do this yourself imho

Comment: @Pekka: Anonymous users don't have the ability to comment. Perhaps, seeing the lack of comment field, they think that's how to comment.

Comment: @badp: Yes there is: http://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/179 → http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4779835/revisions ;) - (And yes, I realize you didn't include the code markup, though I'm not really sure why)

Comment: @sth [ _I_ submitted that edit anonymously.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/468687#468687) I did it to make a point about why diffs should default to show markdown diff instead of rendered output.