# Suggested edits Review page shows the user who proposed the edit as Anonymous user

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

The past few hours or so, I've seen a huge spike in proposed suggested edits by Anonymous users correcting the grammar & actually *fixing* the posts.

[image]:

Going by past trends, this isn't... right. After approving the edit, taking a look at the permalink of the edit suggestion shows the actual user who proposed the edit.

[image]

Comment: It see the same effect on Stack Overflow. (All 29 proposed edits are from the anonymous user).

Comment: It happens on other SE sites as well. I have noticed that on EL&U.

Comment: @Jose, I accepted your edit just to be able to ping you. It is lacking important information: did the user change after approving the edit? (Note that anonymous users are very well allowed to suggest edits!)

Comment: @Arjan: I haven't tested *that* bit properly, please rollback my edit then.

Comment: an't repro this on SU @Arjan

Comment: @Arjan: quick check today shows the user gets updated after approval, In http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7220350/revisions the user is Community♦ so are the anonymous user updates for mods ?

Comment: @Jose, not sure what you mean. Clicking "suggested" in your link shows that an anonymous user suggested it. After approval, it's indeed Community who owns that edit; see [Community♦ user edit: How does it know what to edit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75472/community-user-edit-how-does-it-know-what-to-edit)

Comment: @Arjan: I get it now, I thought it would show some other user instead of Community and that was why I edited this question in the first place. I think this should be rolled back. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6486908/revisions is another example, anonymous user suggests, and Community is the owner after approval.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You aren't imagining it - good spot. Thanks; exactly as you suggest, a recent change meant it wasn't getting the user information to display on that screen (the data itself was fine - it just wasn't visible).

This has been rectified, and will be fixed after we next deploy.

Comment: I believe this has regressed... http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/329448

Comment: @Basic no, that one was genuinely proposed by an anonymous user

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually this  is not fixed. I am seeing the anonymous user thing right now when I click on edit link (next to the share link). I mean it is not the same page, but it is same problem.